# Search by dropdown value using MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, search, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a search function that allows the user to search a column that is specified by a dropdown, I have been able to get the search to work but only by using a specific column and a contains method. Can anyone help?

Below I have included my controller and my view, please let me know if you need any other code. Thanks for your time and help!

I am almost positive that this is the code that I have to alter to use the dropdown to search instead of a specific column.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                IAMP = IAMP.Where(p => p.PA.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())); 
            }
```

### Controller

```
 public class PaController : Controller
    {
        PaEntities db = new PaEntities();

        // Index Method 
        public ViewResult Index(string CurrentField, string sortField, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, string Versions, string VPS, string Directors, string IAMP_SEARCH)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentOrder = sortOrder = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "asc" : sortOrder; // Provides the order to sort
            ViewBag.CurrentField = sortField = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortField) ? "IAMP_PK" : sortField; // Provides the field to sort

            var IAMP = from p in db.iamp_mapping select p;
            var ISER = from s in db.iamp_search_string select s;

            if (Versions != null && Versions != String.Empty) // Version Dropdown Sort Function     
            {
                IAMP = IAMP.Where(v => v.VERSION.Contains(Versions));
            }

            var VIAMP = from x in db.version_number select x;
            var VPIAMP = from v in db.vp_table select v;
            var DIAMP = from d in db.director_table select d;

            ViewData["SelectedVersion"] = Versions;
            ViewData["Versions"] = new SelectList(VIAMP.Select(x => x.VERSION));
            ViewData["VPS"] = new SelectList(VPIAMP.Select(x => x.VP));
            ViewData["Directors"] = new SelectList(DIAMP.Select(x => x.DIRECTOR));
            ViewData["currentFilter"] = currentFilter;
            ViewData["IAMP_SEARCH"] = IAMP_SEARCH;
            ViewData["IAMP_SEARCH"] = new SelectList(ISER.Select(x => x.IAMP_SEARCH));


            if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET") {

                searchString = currentFilter; //sets the currentFilter equal to Searchstring
                IAMP_SEARCH = sortField;
            }
            else {
                page = 1;                   // defaults to page 1
            }
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString; // Provides the view with the current filter string

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                IAMP = IAMP.Where(p => p.PA.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())); 
            }

            switch (sortField) {

                default: IAMP = sortOrder == "asc" ? IAMP.OrderBy(p => p.PA) : IAMP.OrderByDescending(p => p.PA); break;
                case "VERSION": IAMP = sortOrder == "asc"? IAMP.OrderBy(p => p.VERSION) : IAMP.OrderByDescending(p => p.VERSION); break;
                case "MAJOR_PROGRAM": IAMP = sortOrder == "asc" ? IAMP.OrderBy(p => p.MAJOR_PROGRAM) : IAMP.OrderByDescending(p => p.MAJOR_PROGRAM); break;
                case "INVESTMENT_AREA": IAMP = sortOrder == "asc" ? IAMP.OrderBy(p => p.INVESTMENT_AREA) : IAMP.OrderByDescending(p => p.INVESTMENT_AREA); break;
                case "VP": IAMP = sortOrder == "asc" ? IAMP.OrderBy(p => p.VP) : IAMP.OrderByDescending(p => p.VP); break;
                case "DIRECTOR": IAMP = sortOrder == "asc" ? IAMP.OrderBy(p => p.DIRECTOR) : IAMP.OrderByDescending(p => p.DIRECTOR); break;
            }


            int pageSize = 15; // number of records shown on page view
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1); // start page number



            return View(IAMP.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)); // uses pagedList method to return correct page values
        }
```

### VIEW

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<DBFirstMVC.Models.iamp_mapping>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

}

@using PagedList;


<h2 class="corporate sifr">PA Mapping</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Show Version: @Html.DropDownList("Versions","All")
        <input type = "submit" value = "Go" />
    </p>

}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="lefty">
        Find by @Html.DropDownList("IAMP_SEARCH","All"): @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type = "submit" value = "Search" />
    </div>

}

<div class="righty">
    @Html.ActionLink("Add a new PA to the database", "Create")
</div>
<br /><br />

<div>
    <div class="lefty">
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
    of @Model.PageCount
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter, Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion   })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
    }
    else
    {
        @:<<
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @:< Prev
    }

    @if (Model.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter, Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion  })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
    }
    else
    {
        @:Next >
        @Html.Raw(" ")
        @:>>
    }
    </div>
    <div class="righty">
    Showing Records @Model.FirstItemOnPage to @Model.LastItemOnPage from @Model.TotalItemCount
    </div>
</div>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("PA", "", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc", sortField = "PA", Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "PA"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_asc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow asc"/>}
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "desc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "PA"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_desc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow desc"/>}                                                                                           
        </th>
        <th>        
            @Html.ActionLink("MAJOR PROGRAM", "", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc", sortField = "MAJOR_PROGRAM", Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "MAJOR_PROGRAM"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_asc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow asc" />}
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "desc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "MAJOR_PROGRAM"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_desc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow desc"/>}           
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("INVESTMENT AREA", "", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc", sortField = "INVESTMENT_AREA", Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "INVESTMENT_AREA"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_asc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow asc"/>}
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "desc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "INVESTMENT_AREA"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_desc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow desc" />}   
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Version", "", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc", sortField = "VERSION", Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "VERSION"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_asc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow asc" />}
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "desc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "VERSION"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_desc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow desc"/>}   
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("VP", "", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc", sortField = "VP", Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "VP"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_asc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow asc"/>}
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "desc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "VP"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_desc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow desc"/>}   
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("DIRECTOR", "", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc", sortField = "DIRECTOR", Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "asc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "DIRECTOR"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_asc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow asc"/>}
            @if (ViewBag.currentOrder == "desc" && ViewBag.CurrentField == "DIRECTOR"){ <img src="../../Images/ico_tablesortoffset_desc.gif" alt = "table sort arrow desc"/>}   
        </th>       
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@{
    var row_class = "odd";
}

@foreach (var item in Model) {
     row_class = row_class == "odd"? "even" : "odd";    
    <tr class="@row_class">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PA)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MAJOR_PROGRAM)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.INVESTMENT_AREA)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VERSION)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VP)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DIRECTOR)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PA}) |

            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PA})
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<div>
    <div class="lefty">
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
    of @Model.PageCount
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
    }
    else
    {
        @:<<
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @:< Prev
    }

    @if (Model.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion })
    }
    else
    {
        @:Next >
        @Html.Raw(" ")
        @:>>
    }
    </div>
    <div class="righty">
    Showing Records @Model.FirstItemOnPage to @Model.LastItemOnPage from @Model.TotalItemCount
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Download in Excel Format", "PaExcelOutput", new {Versions = ViewBag.SelectedVersion, currentFilter = ViewBag.currentFilter})
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Dynamic Query](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) which allows you to use dynamic column names.

Comment: I have been messing with the dynamic query for two days now and I cannot get it to work. I have found another tool to use called predicate builder and it seems to have what I need, have you ever heard of the predicate builder?

Comment: Yes, I know predicate builder. It allows you to build and chain dynamic where conditions but doesn't allow you to use dynamic column names which is what you need here. Well, you could always write an ugly `switch` statement with all the possible values of the dropdown but using dynamic query seems more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Well I only have about 5 columns that I need to search and I haven't been able to figure out dynamic query yet but I'll give it another shot today and post again here after I have a result. Thanks for your advice!